# Error parsing temporary file image object created with GD library to parse PNG image for PNG images

Tags: mpdf

We use 6.1, updated to PHP 7.4 and now we have this error. _MPDF_TEMP_PATH is writable. It seems that mPDF is not creating the temporary file. It worked in PHP 7.3. Any suggestions where to start debugging? .jpg is still working.

https://github.com/baselbers/mpdf/tree/mpdf

Comment: First, mPDF 6.1 is not officially supported on PHP 7.4. Upgrade to mPDF to 8.0.4 at least. https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/README.md

Comment: Use official mPDF distribution from mpdf/mpdf in packagist.

Comment: Then, add your example code and example image to allow to reproduce the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example